# How do I show a hint on buttons has a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on a C# WinForm application in Visual Studio 2008. I have added keyboard shortcuts to some of the buttons, which triggers a button click (CTRL + R, CTRL B and so on...), by overriding ProcessCmdKey.

When the user press and hold the CTRL key I want to show a hint, tooltip or something next to the button with the shortcut text ("CTRL + R") so the user can see which buttons that has a shortcut and what the combination is.

Does anyone have any other suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You mean whichever control has the focus should receive the CTRL+R key event and display the tooltip ?

Comment: No. All controls that has a shortcut should show its shortcut text when the user press and hold the CTRL-key.

Comment: @Zeno: That's the Alt key, not Ctrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a WPF control that looks similar to a standard tooltip (small box with a label). I then did an override on ProcessCmdKey and OnKeyUp on my form to listen to CTRL key down and key up.

When the user presses and holds down the CTRL key I loop through all my controls that has a shortcut and creates a WPF control on top of that control. For each WPF control I set the corresponding shortcut text. When the CTRL key is released I remove all WPF controls in OnKeyUp.

Comment: I don't understand why you needed to create a WPF control in a WinForms project. You want a tooltip, just use a tooltip. No WPF interop required.

Answer (score 1):

That thing is possible with `&` in Caption. When user presses `Alt` Key, character after `&` in caption of button become Underlined and when user presses that underline character key. click event of button gets fired.

(Sorry forgotting term for this).

Comment: For some reasons we can´t use Alt Key and & in Caption in this project, we must use the CTRL key...